# Save a string with HTML format to doc (with unicode)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I try many way but I don't get the result that I expect. Please help, thanks.

I have a byte array, and I read it to a string, the result is :

`string mystring = "<p>Today is a <b>beautiful</b> day</p>"`

now I want to return it to a DOC file with HTML format.
I have the problem that I cant get a file with unicode format.

This is what I want in doc file :

> Today is a **beautiful** day

Can anyone help me find the way I can save my string to doc file with unicode encode?

Comment: is the DOC file "Windows word document" ? are u trying to convert html file to Word DOC file through code?

Comment: Yes, it is. I tried to save but not unicode format. And it's not html file, I got a string with HTML code in C#
ex : `string mystring="<p>Today is a <b>beautiful</b> day</p>"`

Comment: i don't think this has anything to do with unicode. it's more like you need to figure the proper/different tag-encoding used in word to bold/format text, which is likely not same as html syntax.

Comment: if it's only English is ok but sometime it has character like : `á ả 汉 语` ... It will be displayed as `?`

Comment: Interop.word.dll provides file open as option, so u can simulate the manual saving of file in word. create a html file in local and then open the same in Document.Open() of Interop.word. more info in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.documents.open(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: I want to use FileStreamResult, any ideas? Because I dont want to add any dll to my project for this.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I did it. I use :
 `MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();

                    StreamWriter output = new StreamWriter(stream, Encoding.UTF8, 2 << 22);
                    output.WriteLine("<html><body>" + mystring + "</body></html>");
                    output.Flush();

                    stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

                    return new FileStreamResult(stream, "application/octet-stream") { FileDownloadName = "File.doc" };`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a very simple Word document from C# code, I would use the `.docx` format, and follow the MSDN blog entry [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dmahugh/archive/2006/06/27/649007.aspx).

It includes full sample code to download.

From the page linked to above:

> This code will generate a DOCX that loads in Word 2007 or any other
>   valid Open XML consumer.